# Creating a search portlet in Rational application developer using websphere

Tags: rad, websphere-portal

I am new to portlet development. I am all java, jsp developer. I got an assignment to create a search box and based on the search it should display best possible results after searching the database.

Just as google/ wikipedia does when you enter a search query and the results it displays.

I need help on how to create a portlet for this in Rational Application Developer using webshere.

Thanks in advance.
Kishan Gourav

Answer (score 0):

Developing portlets and developing search capabilities are two topics and the solution you provide may vary depending on your specific requirements.

Getting started on portlets in RAD, samples (all taken from [this page](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/page.xsp?documentId=41D1B94FB3088FC785257BFE000EFE81&action=openDocument) where you can find more resources to get you going):

- [JSR 286 portlet project](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.portal.doc/samples/jsr286_sample.html)
- [Faces portlet using AJAX](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.portal.doc/samples/ajax_sample.html)
- [Web 2.0 portlets](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.portal.doc/samples/Web20_portlets_overview.html)

When it comes to search it depends a lot about what your source for this search is. You are talking about a database in which case it is harder for me to help, but in case you mean you want to search the contents of your portal these resources may help:

- [Faceted Search - Leverage Search Experience based on IBM Search REST API](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Leverage_Search_Expierence_based_on_Portal_Search_REST_API)
- [Customizing and extending the functionality of the IBM WebSphere Portal 6.1 Search Center portlet](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0809_shapiro/0809_shapiro.html) - Old version of the portal but may still give you a nudge in the right direction.
- [Creating a custom IBM WebSphere Portal portlet to search across IBM Web Content Manager, Connections, and Lotus Quickr](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Creating_a_custom_IBM_WebSphere_Portal_portlet_to_search_across_IBM_Web_Content_Managercom__Connectionscom_and_Lotus_Quickr)
- [Portlets for working with Search](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20WebSphere%20Portal%20Express%208%20Product%20Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Portlets_for_working_with_Search_exp8&content=pdcontent) - Not actually any help developing a portlet of your own, but rather an overview of existing search capabilities in the portal.

Keep in mind that these are only resources for developing the actual search portlet. In order for portal search to work you need to have search services configured. Your portal administrators should be able to help you with that or have a look at ['Search' Quick Starter Guide for WebSphere Portal](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/apoSearchapo_Quick_Starter_Guide_for_WebSphere_Portal).